# How the getters and setters work when they are of different classes in this case?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn basic android gaming. And am stuck here. I want a value that need to be set for the string which i can use for later purposes.
In detail

```
    public class Play implements Screen{
        public String Strsun="";
        InputProcessor input=new MyInputProcessor();
        MyInputProcessor z=new MyInputProcessor();
        public Play(Game game) {
             this.game = game;
        }

        public String getStrsun() {
             return Strsun;
        }

        public void setStrsun(String strsun) {
             Strsun = strsun;
        }

        public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input); 
            Strsun=z.getStr();
            System.out.println(Strsun);
        }
    }
```

This is my code in one class
Now my code in second class is

```
    public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor{
        Play sunny;
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            sunny.setStrsun("bunny");
        }
    }
```

But as part of first lines of code my intention is to print bunny.. But it is not working. so how can i print bunny from Play to my console in eclipse.
Thanks in advance

```
   Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: In the future please provide specifics about your problem. "But it is not working." isn't especially helpful. Consider adding the error you're getting and your logcat.

Comment: My question is not about learning sir. I have been commiting some mistakes which i cannot find. So i am just asking where am i doing wrong. Like why i cant print bunny.. Thats it.. My error is LWJGL error.. Which means i am spelling something wrong.. so i just posted what actually i wanted.

Comment: The purpose of the question is irrelevant. Although, I would say it most certainly is about learning as you don't *know* how to fix it. Explaining what errors you're getting and supplying a logcat is to help those who are trying to help you. This isn't a site dedicated to code review. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thank u sir, but am new to this.. Sorry for any inconvenience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the Play object:

```
Play sunny = new Play(/*params go here*/);
```

You should also set Strsun to private instead of public since you only seem to want it to be modifiable by the getStrsun and setStrsun methods rather than directly by other objects.

Edit: Some other minor things:

1. When you create the input an z objects, you use InputProcessor for one and MyInputProcessor for the other. Unless you have a reason for doing this, I'd use MyInputProcessor for both for the sake of consistency.
2. conventionally, variable names shouldn't start with a capital letter (with the exception of constants, which are all caps). so instead of calling the String Strsun, call it strsun, and then in the setter (for example), write:

   `public void setStrsun(String strsun) {
       this.strsun = strsun;
   }`

   Always use the this keyword when referring to variables which belong to the object you're currently in. It makes things less confusing.
3. You have Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input); in the render method. Render will get called once a frame, meaning it will get called 30-60 times a second depending on the frame rate. You probably want to move this to the constructor if you only want it called once.
4. You create a Play object in MyInputProcessor (even though you don't initialize it), and you initialize 2 MyInputProcessor objects in Play. Watch out so you don't have the function calls create an infinite recursion loop, since this will crash your program.

Hope this helps. If you still have questions, try including the error message you get and be as specific as possible about your problem and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank u.. but i missed a part of questn when posted.. That is play method in that class which has an game object.. so can u suggest how to initilaise in detail.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the `Play` object. Do `Play sunny=new Play();` Then you can use getters/setters, when the object is instantiated.

Comment: Thank u.. but i missed a part of questn when posted.. That is play method in that class which has an game object.. so can u suggest how to initilaise in detail.

Comment: When you want to invoke any mathod from an object you have to instatiate it first (create it). You not only need to declare it via Play sunny; you have to create it and allocate some memory for it: Play sunny=new Play();

Comment: Its very helpful thank u. But can u say how can i do that for my code. Because when i create it like play sunny=new play(game); it is showing error i.e.,LWJGL error..

Comment: When you Play sunny=new Play(); you don't put anything between the brackets.